# Nivo bar chart calling label function hundreds of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nivo-slider

I'm using Nivo bar to represent a user's progress on a budget. I've normalized the data by dividing the category balance by the category goal. Example data.

```
[{
    "category": "Gas",
    "budget": 0.24,
    "over_budget": 0.0
},
{
    "category": "Groceries",
    "budget": 1.0,
    "over_budget": 0.26
}]
```

I don't want these values to be used as the label on the chart. I plan to use the actual balance value as the label. I have an endpoint that will return the balance for a category and have attempted the following to use that value:

```
<ResponsiveBar
...
label={d => this.getDollarAmount(d.value)}
...
>
```

With the function POC as:

```
getDollarAmount(value) {
    console.log("hitting getDollarAmount")
    return 1
  };
```

The log message gets logged 500+ times. My expectation would be that the function would only be hit once for each bar in the chart.

I'm still learning react so this could be something obvious. Thanks in advance!

EDIT - Here's the entire BarChart component:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import React, { Component } from "react";

import { ResponsiveBar } from '@nivo/bar'

// Nivo theming
const theme = {
  axis: {
    ticks: {
      line: {
        stroke: "#e9ecee",
        strokeWidth: 40
      },
      text: {
        // fill: "#919eab",
        fill: "black",
        fontFamily: "BlinkMacSystemFont",
        fontSize: 16
      }
    }
  },
  grid: {
    line: {
      stroke: "#e9ecee",
      strokeWidth: 5
    }
  },
  legends: {
    text: {
      fontFamily: "BlinkMacSystemFont"
    }
  }
};

let budgetStatusAPI = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/budget_status/?auth_user=1&month=2020-02-01';

class BarChart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }

    this.getDollarAmount = this.getDollarAmount.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component did mount")

    axios.get(budgetStatusAPI).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        data: response.data
      }, function () {
        console.log(this.state.data);
      })
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("component did update")
  }

  getDollarAmount(value) {
    console.log("hitting getDollarAmount")
    console.log(value)
    return 1
  };


  render() {

    const hard_data = [
        {
          "category": "Groceries",
          "budget_status": 1.0,
          "over_budget": .26,
        },
        {
          "category": "Gas",
          "budget_status": .24,
          "over_budget": 0.0,
        }]

    return(

      <ResponsiveBar
        maxValue={1.5}
        markers={[
            {
                axis: 'x',
                value: 1,
                lineStyle: { stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)', strokeWidth: 2 },
                legend: 'Goal',
                legendOrientation: 'horizontal',
                legendPosition: 'top'
            },
        ]}
        enableGridX={false}
        gridXValues={[1]}
        enableGridY={false}
        data={this.state.data}
        // data={hard_data}
        keys={['budget_status', 'over_budget']}
        indexBy="category"
        margin={{ top: 25, right: 130, bottom: 50, left: 125 }}
        padding={0.3}
        layout="horizontal"
        colors={{ scheme: 'set2' }}
        theme={theme}
        defs={[
            {
                id: 'dots',
                type: 'patternDots',
                background: 'inherit',
                color: '#38bcb2',
                size: 4,
                padding: 1,
                stagger: true
            },
            {
                id: 'lines',
                type: 'patternLines',
                background: 'inherit',
                color: '#eed312',
                rotation: -45,
                lineWidth: 6,
                spacing: 10
            }
        ]}
        borderColor={{ from: 'color', modifiers: [ [ 'darker', 1.6 ] ] }}
        axisBottom={null}
        label={d => this.getDollarAmount(d.value)}
        isInteractive={false}
        animate={true}
        motionStiffness={90}
        motionDamping={15}
    />
    )
  }
}


export default BarChart;
```

Reproduced here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nivo-bar-label-issue-k4qek

Comment: There is something in your compoment (*or other app state management*) code that triggers multiple renders. Please provide the full component code.

Comment: I've added the entire component. I have noticed that when I use the hard-coded values for my data, this issue doesn't occur. If I use the data grabbed from the state, it occurs.

Comment: I have reproduced this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nivo-bar-label-issue-k4qek still not sure why its happening though.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple calling is happening because the bar chart is calling `label` function for each animation tick/frame render. If we setup a counter, we'll see with `animate` prop set to `true` it will render from `450+` to `550+` times, but if we set the prop `animate` to `false`, we'll it renders `6` times which is exactly how many price values are `> 0.0`.

If you want to avoid all these renders, you'll have to disable animation using `animate={false}` prop like this:

```jsx
getDollarAmount(value) {
  // Remove every console.log inside this function

  return `$${value}`
}

render() {
  return (
    <ResponsiveBar
      animate={false}
      label={d => this.getDollarAmount(d.value)}
      ...
  );
}
```

You can check it running to your cloned [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nivo-bar-label-issue-sc95t). I have set `animate` to `false` and the `counter` log inside `getDollarAmount` is calling `6` times. Try to change `animate` to `true` and you'll see the `500+-` renders.

Also, you don't have to create a function for each `label` call, you can just pass the `getDollarAmount` function and let it handle the whole `d` parameter like this:

```jsx
getDollarAmount(d) {
  // Remove every console.log inside this function

  return `$${d.value}`
}

render() {
  return (
    <ResponsiveBar
      animate={false}
      label={this.getDollarAmount}
      ...
  );
}
```

Comment: How do I know that its not still calling the function hundreds of times?

Comment: @brewcrazy you're right, this was not the culprit, the animation is. Check my updated answer.